# Inline transaltion no longer editable

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, database, table, inline-translations

Hi I have an inline translation which is no longer showing up with a red box around it, and so I am unable to edit the content from the front end.

Inspecting the element it should be held in "mage_catalog" is there a way to go directly into the database and make the amendments?

If not is there a workaround to target this field and change the text.

```
<span translate="[{
"shown":"<div><table><tr><td>Please call for details<br>0203 011 1968<\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/div>",
"translated":"<div><table><tr><td>Please call for details<br>0203 011 1968<\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/div>",
"original":"Out of stock","location":"Span element","scope":"Mage_Catalog"}]"></span>
```

Comment: I know that there is a problem with these translations and a version of chrome, any chance this is also your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the database use the translate csv's.
It should be in `app/local/[language]/Mage_Catalog.csv`.

More info about the Magento translations csv's can be found [here](http://blog.belvg.com/editing-magento-translate-csv-file.html).